# SaddlePoint Approximation Score Statistic

Tags: chi-squared-distribution, saddlepoint-approximation

My question will be very practical. Actually, I work in statistical genetics and I have 1000 Score statistics for which I want to compute the corresponding p-values. To be more specific, I suppose a conditional retrospective model:

$P(G|Y) = \frac{\exp{(\beta\sum_ig_{i}P(G_i))}} {\sum_{G^*}\exp{(\beta\sum_ig_{i*}P(G_i*))}}$

where  $g_i$ = {0, 1, 2}, is the number of minor alleles for one variant in an individual i and P(Gi) the corresponding probability to observe this variant. The denominator corresponding to the sum of all possible genotypic configurations. Here we can suppose a log-linear model of the variant effect.

Since I computed the Score statistic and the related Covariance matrix, I know that:

$Q = S^tV^{-1}S \sim \chi_{1}$ under the null.

However, asymptotic theory does not work very well in my tails (as expected due to rare variants i.e., lot of zero), providing inflation of Type I error. I read that Saddlepoint approximation might be a excellent solution to this problem since it uses the entire cumulant-generating function (CGF), while when we use normal approximation only the two first cumulants are used (mean and variance, respectively).

Some methods have been proposed to compute p-values (Lugannani and Rice, 1980) but it is not clear for me how to use it in my context.

To my current knowledge, here I may compute approximated distribution using the moment-generating function (MGF) of a poisson distribution. In this paper (https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.10.31.358234v1.full.pdf) authors use closed approach.

If anyone have inputs it would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give some more details on your setup? What is your model(s)? How do you calculate the score statistics? ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I did an edit on my post, thanks .